# Javascript function only starts when page is reloaded manually

Tags: javascript, html, flow-router

I  have a function that works as it should, but only if the page is reloaded after landing on the specific page.

The function is a timer function that starts to tic down from 10 to 0 when the page is loaded (it should work like this).

But I land on the page and nothing happens. When I reload the page the timer starts and works...

I have tried $(document).on and window.onload = function() but with no success.

```js
FlowRouter.route("/waitingForPlayer", {
  name: "waitingForPlayer",
  action() {
    BlazeLayout.render("iphone", { main: "waitingForPlayer" });
    console.log("first");
    window.onload = startTimer;

    function startTimer(duration, display) {
      console.log("second");
      var timer = duration,
        seconds;
      setInterval(function() {
        console.log("third");
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "" + seconds : seconds;
        display.textContent = seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
          timer = duration;
        }
        if (timer == 0) {
          FlowRouter.go("readyForGame");
          document.location.reload(true);
        }
      }, 1000);
    }

    window.onload = function() {
      var fiveMinutes = 10,
        display = document.querySelector("#time");
      startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
    };
  }
});
```

When the timer is = 0 the `flowrouter` changes view.

Comment: You have two window.onload calls, it’s better to put all your onload code in one function

Comment: I tried to put everything under one window.onload but still no success. @Kokodoko

Comment: I would recommend looking into how [Triggers](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#triggers) work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you put `onload` function inside the router callback. You don't need to run `window.onload` inside router's callback because it's `Single page application` router. Try to look for `onComplete` event of the flow-router library. I think that `action` is the callback for complete event of the router.

Example:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  console.log("second");
  var timer = duration, seconds;

  setInterval(function() {
    console.log("third");
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    seconds = ('0' + seconds).slice(-2);

    display.innerText = seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }
    if (timer == 0) {
      FlowRouter.go("readyForGame");
    }
  }, 1000);
}

FlowRouter.route("/waitingForPlayer", {
  name: "waitingForPlayer",
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render("iphone", { main: "waitingForPlayer" });
    console.log("first");

    var fiveMinutes = 10,
      display = document.querySelector("#time");
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? onComplete: function startTimer(duration, display) { my function } @pbibergal

Comment: I edited my answer, tell me if it works. The `startTimer` function has to be outside. You don't want to redeclare it each time the router completes action.

Comment: it runs the "third" console log directly now but I get errors in the console:" main.js:88 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null" and the timer doesn't start. @pbibergal

Comment: Maybe it's because `document.querySelector("#time")` doesn't have such function. Try `innerText`. See my in edit, `('0' + seconds).slice(-2)` is better way to add zero to numbers less than 10.

Comment: still got this error :/ Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null at main.js:88 @pbibergal

Comment: Perhaps that's because you are trying to access DOM element in template that's being rendered dynamically. You'll have then to pass the seconds variable to template, and rerender each time. (Assuming, i'm not familiar with BlazeLayout nor FlowRouter).
Maybe try next time to use Angular or Vue, they are more dedicated for SPA